How fast and far do electrons move in a diode during reverse bias?
When I have looked at videos on how diodes work, they make it seem like the electrons move extraordinarily quickly during reverse bias and quite a bit to expand the depletion regions. However, I would theorize that they move slowly and not very much (which is still significant) because we know the drift velocity of electrons is slow, and I would imagine reverse bias expands the depletion regions pretty quickly (ergo the electrons don't move far since they move slowly for not a long time). However, am I wrong? If so, then why? I thought that electrons moved slowly during electricity, and the depletion region expanded really quickly (possibly 1/1000 or 1/100 of a second) since a little bit of movement is very significant (possibly a few nanometers). Once again, if I am wrong about anything, then please tell me why I am wrong. Thank you all very much!

In metals the drift velocity is very slow at sensible currents because there are so many available electrons, however the carrier density even in a doped semiconductor is many, many orders of magnitude smaller so the electrons have to move proportionally faster at the same current (I'm guessing maybe 10^8 times faster). That's some hand waving. maybe an answer will appear with some realistic numbers.

I was imagining that electrons move at the "same speed" (quasi ...) ... then in Cu. But I could be wrong ...

https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/speed-electrons-conductor-nicolas-enguehard

Current is the flow of charge with 1A = 1C/s or ~6E+18 electrons per second. Copper has ~6E22 electrons/cm^3. Keep in mind too (although it does not affect the numbers here, but for visualization), that the  electron drift in a metal due to current is like a tiny statistical anomaly in the thermal motion of the electrons, which is something like 10^9 faster at room temperature.

An odd case -- in an Esaki (tunnel) diode, do some of those electrons move, or just disappear in one spot and reappear in another, on the other side of the barrier? Quantum tunneling is not intuitive.
